# Rep and removed users

Tags: support

I recently had someone [downvote an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18894/filtering-on-a-virtual-column-from-a-union-all-with-left-outer-join-causes-a-tab/18895#18895) and when I saw the rep explanation on my account it said "user was removed".

This is kind of difficult to understand why I lost reputation. I'm assuming they were removed due to some sort of moderator intervention. If that is the case, would it not be sensible to receive back the lost reputation? Or to at least have an explanation of why they thought the answer was bad. It is hard to better help the community if there no feedback. Plus since I'm one of the few DB2 contributors to this site, my reputation growth is slower than others and it is frustrating to lose reputation for no apparent reason.

I guess I just want to understand the situation.

Comment: If moderators remove a user, any votes from that user are nullified. If they downvoted an answer, you would have gotten a "refund" on the answer when they were deleted. As it is, we can't really see who voted (that would be against their privacy) so if you really want to try and push an issue, it'll have to be with the devs. (It looks like, in retrospect, they upvoted one of your questions, since you lost five points)

Comment: And for the record, I removed one user yesterday who was only spamming the site with answers for his product.

Comment: Well, thnx for the help. I figured as such. I appreciate your looking into it and providing feedback.

Comment: @jcolebrand You should put that in an answer. ;)

Comment: Which one Anna, because there's two parts to the problem :p ~ I also wasn't sure that this had an _answer_ per-se. However, I know better than to argue with a community team member ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer form, altogether now:

If moderators remove a user, any votes from that user are nullified. If they downvoted an answer, you would have gotten a "refund" on the answer when they were deleted. As it is, we can't really see who voted (that would be against their privacy) so if you really want to try and push an issue, it'll have to be with the devs. (It looks like, in retrospect, they upvoted one of your questions, since you lost five points)

And for the record, I removed one user on June 5th, 2012 who was only spamming the site with answers for his product.