# what does "User was removed" mean?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rep and removed users](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/712/rep-and-removed-users)

I noticed I lost 5 rep because "User was removed" - not worried about the rep, but curious as to what this means?